# How should I get the far plane vertex data of the view frustum

Tags: gis, cesiumjs

I want to get the vertex data of the far plane of the view frustum, but I found that in cesium, I can’t get the correct upward direction of the view frustum I created. I want to know how to get the four far planes of any view frustum. The coordinates of the vertex

[text](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

If there are multiple frustums in cesium, the upward direction of the frustum camera cannot be correctly obtained.